# When to add imageView to UIButton when using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

Currently I have multiple `UIButton`s that have an image on the left side (added through the IB). I'd like to add a UIImageView subview to the buttons programatically  to the right side. Currently I am doing it in this manner:

```
UIImageView *rightArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-arrow.png"]];
rightArrow.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.size.width - 32, button.frame.size.height/2 - 9, 17, 17);
rightArrow.tag = 22;
[button addSubview:rightArrow];
```

This works great in adding the button and placing it on the right side. However, doing this in the `ViewDidLoad` method creates issues. In the IB the width of the button is the width of the view. So in the `ViewDidLoad` method the button's width hasn't been changed by autolayout. So it doesn't show up on the far right side.

So I moved it to the `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`. But on iOS 8, this is called multiple times! And on iOS 7 it's called once! Also, in iOS 8 the LAST call by `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` is the most accurate in terms of placing the image!

How can I solve this particular issue? Also I'd like to do this programatically rather than try and mess with the IB if possible.

Edit: Turns out the best answer (IMO) was from Mr. T (in the comments) which stats putting the code in `ViewDidAppear` and then doing a check if you've already added the `ImageView`to the button.

Comment: try in viewDidAppear insteadof viewdidload

Comment: @Mr.T I could add it there, except then I'd have to do a check to make sure I didn't already add the image for every button. Every time the view appeared but didn't actually unload.

Comment: "except then I'd have to do a check to make sure I didn't already add the image for every button" What sort of objection is that? That's what coding _is_.

Comment: @matt seems I worded it improperly. I meant that it wasn't a particularly elegant solution. I think subclassing UIButton would be better which is what I believe you suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But on iOS 8, this is called multiple times! And on iOS 7 it's called once! Also, in iOS 8 the LAST call by ViewDidLayoutSubviews is the most accurate in terms of placing the image!

So respond *each* time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called. If the image view is already added, don't add it again — but do reposition it if necessary.

An even better approach, however, would be be to position the image view itself using autolayout! Instead of assigning it a frame, give it constraints. Now it will be repositioned *automatically* in response to view layout, for the rest of time.

Comment: In my question I mentioned I had multiple buttons that needed this applied. I'd have to create multiple (in this case 8) images and align them with the buttons. While this isn't necessarily too much, I was looking for a solution that was programmatic. How would your solution look for "respond and reposition each time", specifically how would you know to reposition?

Comment: First of all, use my second approach, namely autolayout; now there is no further code needed. Moreover, if you generate the button from its own _.xib_ file each time you need it, or if you use a button subclass that attaches the image view _to itself_, you don't have to do this over and over again for each button that gets this treatment. Right?